# Accuracy of 0.0 using Scikit Naive-Bayes model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I'm trying to use a basic Naive-Bayes Classifier in Python using VSC. My attempts all yield 0.0 accuracy.

This is **sample data**: A CSV without header, of format

```
class,"['item1','item2','etc']"
```

The goal is to fit this data to a Multinomial NB model. This is my attempt at it:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=',',names=['class','words'],encoding='utf-8')


#x is independent var/feature 
X = df.drop('class',axis=1)
#y is dependent var/label
Y = df['class']

#split data into train/test splits, use 25% of data for testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.25,random_state = 42)

#create a sparse matrix of words; each word is assigned a number and frequency is counted (i.e. word "x" occurs n amount of times in class Z), rows are classes, columns are words

cv = CountVectorizer()


X_tr = cv.fit_transform(X_train.words)
X_te = cv.transform(X_test.words)

model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(X_tr,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_te)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
# accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)*100
# print(accuracy)
```

**As I understand it the following occurs:**
A dataframe, df, is created, and split into X and Y (words and classes)

The data's collectively split into training/testing groups

The count vectorizer, CV, assigns an index to each word and counts how many times a certain word occurs in a certain class (word occurences as numbers)

A Multinomial model is created and fit with the training data (x_train.words is used so as the "words" label is ignored)

the model is tested with testing data and an accuracy score is printed.

**I've already tried:**
Checking the shape of the x_test and x_train dataframe: they match like I think they should, with an equal amount of columns (words), and a 6:3 ratio of rows (classes, per the train test split)

Checking the variable types: the training and testing x's are all sparse matrices (<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>) and the  testing/training y's are, per the parameters of model.fit, array-like shapes of n samples (pandas series).

**The Issue** is that the accuracy is 0.0, meaning something's wrong. Perhaps the greater issue is that I have no idea what.

Comment: Kindly share a link toi your csv file.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat I'm using the data from [this](https://github.com/jacobshk/Naive-Bayes-Research-V2/blob/main/Datasets/Processed%20English/merged-data-file.csv) repo

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the length of your whole data frame is just 9. Just 9 rows. So your model doesn't learn anything. Also, I checked your dataset and I don't think you can make a sentence classifier from it as there are no sentences in your dataset.

Comment: I was under the impression that 9 rows representing 9 classes would be sufficient for at least a small scale model — if not, how many classes are sufficient? Also, isn’t the data a matrix of 9 classes with 40,400 columns (words)? I thought the classifier could associate individual words from the list in X with classes?   Clearly I’m misunderstanding but could you point me in the right direction or explain where I’m going wrong?

Comment: I think I understand where I went wrong: the csv should be of format "class, [doc1, doc2, docn]" where the docs are lists of words, right? So the X variable is a list of lists of strings?

Comment: yes. the format should be "class, [doc1, doc2, doc...... docn]". That way for a class you will have n docs. Now you can make a classifier.

Comment: I understand the data input part, but now I'm confused on the train/test split -- How do I make a train/test split that covers all the possible classes in the data and takes a percentage from that group, rather than only covering a percentage of the total classes? Currently, the 25% test split contains 3 of the 9 total classes (6 classes being in the train split) this obviously means the classifier won't be accurate because it wasn't trained on all possible classes.

Comment: @BobSmith You are supposed to make a multiple rows from the "class, [doc1, doc2, doc...... docn]" as row1 = ["class", "doc1"], row2 = ["class", "doc2"] and so on and this for all the classes.